# Doing Deep-Nested Parent-Child Relationships using FeathersJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, feathersjs

I am wondering what the best way to do deep nested parent child relationships is using Feathers's [recommended Association Method?](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#the-preferred-way)

If my entries were:

```
[
    {"name": "Grandpa", "id": 1, "parent": null},
    {"name": "Mom", "id":2, "parent": 1},
    {"name": "Baby", "id": 3, "parent": 2}
]
```

Then if I wanted to find the top parent of the tree, I would do a recursive get until I reach the top of the tree:

```
const family = app.service('/family')
function get_ancestors(childId, parents){
    const child = family.get(childId)
    if(child.parent){
        parents.push(child.parent)
        return get_ancestors(child.parent, parents)
    } else {
        return parents
    }
}
```

But this seems clunky to me and not very extendable. Is there a better way?
This seems like something [fastJoin](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/guide.html#fastJoin) would do, but it is not under the "Recommended" approach to doing associations. I also don't see any examples of more than 3 levels in the guide, except in maybe the [batch-loaders,](https://feathers-plus.github.io/v1/feathers-hooks-common/guide.html#Batch-loaders)
And that looks to be a little more complex than we need here. What is the "recommended" way of traversing an ancestor tree using Feathers?
Conversely, If I had Grandpa, how would I find Baby?
Should my entries contain a "children" array that populates when a child is added with them as a parent? Or is there a better way of going from the top to the bottom of a parent tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it comes down to is that Feathers is *not* an ORM, so handling associations depends a lot on the database and ORM you chose much the same as it would with other frameworks like Express or KoaJS. It means more flexibility but also that there isn't really the one true way to do this and the FAQ entry linked tries to cover the different options as good as possible.

`fastJoin` does support nested associations but may be slower if you are using an SQL database where the ORM could handle optimizing the queries (Sequelize also supports nested includes). But it can be faster than Mongoose `$populate`. Run some experiments to see which one works best. With parent/child relationships one thing to look out for is circular dependencies so you want to use something that can handle that.

Comment: In src/models/my_service.model.js for a Sequelize service, I see http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/ in the comments. So I just set up the association, then in future GET calls, Sequelize will populate parent fields with data? The problem is that the above documentation does not talk about the .associate function, instead, it looks as if they are passing a model where the hooks are being passed and then calling another function like .belongsTo.

Comment: They also always have both associated Sequelize model objects in the same document. Do I just import the exported object from the other service.model.js file and use that? If I'm using ids from the same model, do I just pass in the current model's name as the modelName?

Comment: The associate function is called on application start. It's called on application start and has the `model` as the argument for that reason, so that we can avoid circular includes. You can use the `models.myModel` in that method to define the association.

Comment: When I use ptestModel1.hasMany(models['ptestModel2']) in the associate function in the ptestModel1.model.js file, I get a crash that happens in the associate function, but with no error text given, just a trace that starts in the Object.keys(models).forEach. This error happens if I do the above in the ptestModel1 model.js file, and the ptestModel2.model.js file if I write ptestModel2.belongsTo(model['ptestModel1']). I tried with and without sequelize.sync({force: true}) and the crash still happened. Do you know what may be causing the crash?

Comment: https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize/issues/20#issuecomment-498763355 answered my question. I was not considering that ptestModel1 would be ptestModel_1. Other than that, the examples in the above issue answer these questions.